# Create Global Cube with measurements from multiple cubes

Tags: ssas, ssms, mdx, cubes

I have 2 cubes each with their own measurements. Some measurements from one cube are linked to to the second. For some reason, the query won't run if I use said linked measurements, but it will run it I only include measurements from the cube I'm selecting from. Now, from what I've read it doesn't look possible but I'd thought I'd check SO to be 100% sure and figure out a work around.

So, is there a way to select measurements from multiple cubes?

**Cube Structure:**

```
CUB1
  Measures
    FCT CUB1
      Measure1
      Measure2
  Dimensions
    Dim1
    Dim2

CUB2
  Measures
    FCT CUB1 // linked measurements
      Measure1
      Measure2
    FCT CUB2
      Measure3
      Measure4
      Measure5
  Dimensions
    Dim1
    Dim2
```

I have created a MDX query based on this section of MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145581.aspx

**Query to create global cube on desktop:**

```
CREATE GLOBAL CUBE [LocalTest]
STORAGE 'C:\LocalCube.cub'
FROM [CUB2]
(
  MEASURE [FCT CUB2].[Measure1], // does not work with this
  MEASURE [FCT CUB2].[Measure3], // here on is fine 
  DIMENSION [FCT CUB2].[Dim1],
  DIMENSION [FCT CUB2].[Dim2]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never used the GLOBAL CUBE command so cannot comment on that. There is another way to refer to a measure in another cube, using the LOOKUPCUBE function. It can be a performance hit though. The only way to know is to test it. You can learn about the LOOKUPCUBE function here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144720.aspx